# How do I use the scrollbar inside of netbeans editor, Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have a long form and I need to scroll it to select a control that is at bottom. How do I do that?

Comment: First, learn how to code a GUI using pure, plain old Java. Then the answer should be obvious. People generally won't teach you how to use an IDE, especially not a GUI builder.

Answer (score 0):

**Creating a new Form with Scroll Bars using NetBeans GUI Builder:**

- In the NetBeans **Projects** panel select the Package within the Project
  you want to create a JFrame form in;
- Right-Click on this package name and from the pop-up menus select
  **New**  **JFrame Form**. A new JFrame form will be displayed within the GUI Builder of NetBeans;
- Size this form to what you want and apply the properties you want
  like Title, DefaultCloseOperation, AlwaysOnTop, Generate Center, etc)
  in the **Properties** Pane of the IDE;
- In the **Pallet** Pane of the IDE select **Scroll Pane**
  (JScrollPane) from the **Swing Containers** section and drag & drop
  it into the new JFrame window. Size the **Scroll Pane** component to
  be the full size of the JFrame Form;
- Again, in the **Pallet** Pane of the IDE select **Panel** (JPanel)
  from the **Swing Containers** section and drag & drop it into the new
  **Scroll Pane** component. The JPanel should automatically size up to the size of the Scroll Pane;
- Now drag & drop all the Swing components you want on your form into
  this **JPanel**. Enlarge the JFrame form if you have to to get all
  the components in then resize your form to what you want when done;
- You now have a JFrame window with a Scroll Pane.

**Creating a *new* JFrame form with Scroll Bars and displaying an existing JFrame form within that Scroll Pane using NetBeans GUI Builder and a little bit of code:**

- In the NetBeans **Projects** panel select the Package within the Project
  you want to create a JFrame form in;
- Right-Click on this package name and from the pop-up menus select
  **New**  **JFrame Form**. A new JFrame form will be displayed within the GUI Builder of NetBeans;
- Size this form to what you want and apply the properties you want
  like Title, DefaultCloseOperation, AlwaysOnTop, Generate Center, etc)
  in the **Properties** Pane of the IDE;
- In the **Pallet** Pane of the IDE select **Scroll Pane**
  (JScrollPane) from the **Swing Containers** section and drag & drop
  it into the new JFrame window. Size the **Scroll Pane** component to
  be the full size of the JFrame Form. Keep the auto-assigned variable name which should be **jScrollPane1**;
- Switch to source code by selecting the **Source** tab in the IDE and navigate to the class constructor;
- Directly after the `initComponents();` method call, make a call to
  the new private method named: `moreInitialization()`. This new method
  would look something like this:

  ```
  private void moreInitialization() {
      /* Instantiate the form you want to display within the
         new form with scroll bars, for example, if the Form 
         class you want to view within Scroll-Bars is named 
         'MainForm' then...                                */
      MainForm mf = new MainForm();
      jScrollPane1.setViewportView(mf.getContentPane());
      setSize(mf.getPreferredSize().width + 20, mf.getPreferredSize().height + 20);
      setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  }
  ```
- Display the new Scroll-Bar Form from the **main()** method with:

  ```
  java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          new jFrame1.setVisible(true);
      }
  });
  ```
- Resize the form to see and use the Scroll Bars.

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround will be creating a JPanel form in netbeans. Then, include it to a scroll pane (by dragging and dropping the file from either file/project view in to the file where the scroll pane in located).